# Replace multiple values in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace multiple values in a column. Suppose you have a column called 'var1' in dataframe.

```
testing <- data.frame(var1 = c(LETTERS[1:5], 
                               'Payments12',
                               'Balance',
                               'Default',
                               'Currentterm',
                               'Interest',
                               'Original.Valuation1',
                               'REV_Capped',
                               'Amount',
                               'NoofHoliday'))
```

I want to replace Left hand side with Right hand side. If any value is not found, it should be unchanged (as it is).

```
c('Payments12' = 'No. of Payments in 12 Months')
c('Balance' = 'Current Balance Bands')
c('Default' = 'Default (>=3 Months)')
c('Currentterm' = 'Current Term')
c('Interest' = 'Interest Rate')
c('Original.Valuation1' = 'Original Valuation')
c('REV_Capped' = 'REV Capped')
c('Amount' = 'Payment received in 12 Months')
c('NoofHoliday' = 'No of Months Holiday')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question is tagged in dplyr, you can use dplyr::mutate and dplyr::recode for this kind of question. If the problem is more complex (with conditions for example) you can use dplyr::case_when

In the exemple above, the code would be like this. Only given recode values will be changed.

```
library(dplyr)
testing <- data.frame(var1 = c(LETTERS[1:5], 
                               'Payments12',
                               'Balance',
                               'Default',
                               'Currentterm',
                               'Interest',
                               'Original.Valuation1',
                               'REV_Capped',
                               'Amount',
                               'NoofHoliday')) %>%
  mutate(var1 = recode(var1, 
                'Payments12' = 'No. of Payments in 12 Months', 
                'Balance' = 'Current Balance Bands',
                'Default' = 'Default (>=3 Months)',
                'Currentterm' = 'Current Term',
                'Interest' = 'Interest Rate',
                'Original.Valuation1' = 'Original Valuation',
                'REV_Capped' = 'REV Capped',
                'Amount' = 'Payment received in 12 Months',
                'NoofHoliday' = 'No of Months Holiday'))
```

Comment: Is there any chance to put the second recode argument in a named vector?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the vector to dataframe using `enframe` and then do a join :

```
library(dplyr)

tibble::enframe(vec, name = 'var1') %>%
   right_join(testing, by = 'var1') %>%
   mutate(result = coalesce(value, var1))

# A tibble: 14 x 3
#   var1                value                         result                       
#   <chr>               <chr>                         <chr>                        
# 1 Payments12          No. of Payments in 12 Months  No. of Payments in 12 Months 
# 2 Balance             Current Balance Bands         Current Balance Bands        
# 3 Default             Default (>=3 Months)          Default (>=3 Months)         
# 4 Currentterm         Current Term                  Current Term                 
# 5 Interest            Interest Rate                 Interest Rate                
# 6 Original.Valuation1 Original Valuation            Original Valuation           
# 7 REV_Capped          REV Capped                    REV Capped                   
# 8 Amount              Payment received in 12 Months Payment received in 12 Months
# 9 NoofHoliday         No of Months Holiday          No of Months Holiday         
#10 A                   NA                            A                            
#11 B                   NA                            B                            
#12 C                   NA                            C                            
#13 D                   NA                            D                            
#14 E                   NA                            E
```

---

In base R, you can do similarly using `merge` + `stack`

```
transform(merge(stack(vec), testing, by.x = 'ind', by.y = 'var1', all.y = TRUE), 
          result = ifelse(is.na(values), as.character(ind), values))
```

**data**

```
vec <- c('Payments12' = 'No. of Payments in 12 Months',
         'Balance' = 'Current Balance Bands',
         'Default' = 'Default (>=3 Months)',
         'Currentterm' = 'Current Term',
         'Interest' = 'Interest Rate',
         'Original.Valuation1' = 'Original Valuation',
         'REV_Capped' = 'REV Capped',
         'Amount' = 'Payment received in 12 Months',
         'NoofHoliday' = 'No of Months Holiday')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
to_update <- testing$var1 %in% names(lut)
testing$var1[to_update] <- lut[testing$var1[to_update]]

testing
#                             var1
# 1                              A
# 2                              B
# 3                              C
# 4                              D
# 5                              E
# 6   No. of Payments in 12 Months
# 7          Current Balance Bands
# 8           Default (>=3 Months,
# 9                   Current Term
# 10                 Interest Rate
# 11            Original Valuation
# 12                    REV Capped
# 13 Payment received in 12 Months
# 14          No of Months Holiday
```

This logic works nicely with `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)
testing$var1[testing$var1 %in% names(lut)] %<>% lut[.]
```

Data

```
testing <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(
    LETTERS[1:5], 'Payments12', 'Balance', 'Default', 'Currentterm', 'Interest',
    'Original.Valuation1', 'REV_Capped', 'Amount', 'NoofHoliday'
  )
)
lut <- c(
  'Payments12' = 'No. of Payments in 12 Months', 
  'Balance' = 'Current Balance Bands', 
  'Default' = 'Default (>=3 Months,', 
  'Currentterm' = 'Current Term', 
  'Interest' = 'Interest Rate', 
  'Original.Valuation1' = 'Original Valuation', 
  'REV_Capped' = 'REV Capped', 
  'Amount' = 'Payment received in 12 Months', 
  'NoofHoliday' = 'No of Months Holiday'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution using case_when:

```
library(tidyverse)
testing %>% mutate(var1 = case_when(var1 == 'Payments12' ~ 'No. of Payments in 12 Months',
                                    var1 == 'Balance' ~ 'Current Balance Bands',
                                    var1 == 'Default' ~ 'Default (>=3 Months)',
                                    var1 == 'Currentterm' ~ 'Current Term',
                                    var1 == 'Interest' ~ 'Interest Rate',
                                    var1 == 'Original.Valuation1' ~ 'Original Valuation',
                                    var1 == 'REV_Capped' ~ 'REV Capped',
                                    var1 == 'Amount' ~ 'Payment received in 12 Months',
                                    var1 == 'NoofHoliday' ~ 'No of Months Holiday',
                                    TRUE ~ as.character(var1)))
```